# Multiple bootstrap modals in one page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

Hello I have Bootstrap Modals on my landing page

I have many bootstrap buttons with different data targets and modals.
The content inside the modal must be displayed based on the buttons data target which is connected to the modal via modals ID
How can I solve this without duplication of code?

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLabel">Read more</button>



<div class="modal fade" id="exampleaModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Example</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <img src="" alt="" class="img-fluid mb-5" />
                        <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data- 
                    dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: _How can I solve this without duplication of code_ What that mean? Because you must duplicate the code and change `id` and `data-target`

Comment: In this way I must duplicate button and modal and put different id and data-target

Comment: You mean one modal and multiple button for the same modal?

Comment: I mean one modal with different content displayed based on the which button is pressed

Comment: I have a bootstrap card, each card has a button which is the modals button. So after pressing the button I need to be displayed the right content.

Comment: Where data come? because in this case 99% of time if is not dynamic the best is duplicate card/button and modal.

Comment: I want to put data in localstorage because there is not any special information

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:-

Multiple bootstrap modals in one page with the help of jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  // Initializing our modal.
  $('#myModal').modal({
    backdrop: 'static',
    keyboard: false,
    show: false,
  });

  $(document).on("click", ".modalButton", function() {

    var ClickedButton = $(this).data("name");

    // You can make an ajax call here if you want. 
    // Get the data and append it to a modal body.


    $(".modal-body").html("<p>" + ClickedButton + "</p> <p>Some text in the modal.</p> ");
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 1" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 1</button>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 2" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 2</button>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 3" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 3</button>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 4" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 4</button>
    <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-lg modalButton" data-name="Clicked Modal 5" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal 5</button>
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```